# Assign CSS if sibling's child is present

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
     <div class="ccm-page">
          <div class="ads-top">
               <div class="adsbygoogle"></div>
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="ttb-panel"><div>
</body>
```

How can I assign CSS to `ttb-panel` div, if `adsbygoogle` class is present, and if that `adsbygoogle` div is not present, how to assign different CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, what you're looking for **cannot be currently achieved with CSS without modifying your markup**.

Your best bet is to apply a class on the `body` or the `div.ccm-page` and then use ancestor selectors or adjacent selectors as needed.

Here are some examples using an new `ad-supported` class:
Assuming the `ad-supported` class is added on the `body` tag, then

```
.ad-supported .ttb-panel {...}
```

or if the new class is on the adjacent `div` prior the `ttb-panel` div, then

```
.ad-supported + ttb-panel {...}
```

Currently, CSS selectors can only check ancestors or siblings.  I'm not aware of any specifications that allows you dig deeper into an adjacent sibling.